Allow suspended users to follow/unfollow posts

Feature request: Allow suspended users to follow/unfollow posts.
Current behavior: Suspended users are not allowed to follow/unfollow posts.


Related answer

To add to the confusion, it seems like you are able to follow and unfollow, as when you click the button it will changing from follow to following and vice versa, but it does not actually notify you.

In that case it's a bug, there shouldn't be an error message if the user can perform the action.

Ah, I think you got confused by the following behavior: "After clicking the 'follow' link under the post, it changes to 'following' (and vice versa) along with the error popup but after refreshing the page the follow status goes back to the original setting" (taken from the linked bug report.)
